# How do I draw a circular gradient?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, gdi+

How do I draw a circular gradient [like this](http://psfreak.com/images/tutorials/elegant-navigation-box/back.jpg) in vb.net?

[image: A Red Circular Gradient]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out this [great page](https://web.archive.org/web/20140906083853/http://bobpowell.net/pgb.aspx). The code in the article is in C#. Here is a VB.NET port of the code you're interested in and updated for a rectangular fill (based on the article's triangle fill sample):

```
    Dim pgb As New PathGradientBrush(New Point() { _
        New Point(0, 0), _
        New Point(0, Me.ClientRectangle.Height), _
        New Point(Me.ClientRectangle.Width, Me.ClientRectangle.Height), _
        New Point(Me.ClientRectangle.Width, 0)})
pgb.SurroundColors = New Color() {Color.Red}
pgb.CenterColor = Color.Gray
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(pgb, Me.ClientRectangle)
pgb.Dispose()
```

Here's another possible solution:

```
Dim pth As New GraphicsPath()
pth.AddEllipse(Me.ClientRectangle)
Dim pgb As New PathGradientBrush(pth)
pgb.SurroundColors = New Color() {Color.Red}
pgb.CenterColor = Color.Gray
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(pgb, Me.ClientRectangle)
```

Note that this last code snippet will draw a circle bounded inside of a rectangle. If you want the circular gradient to fill the entire rectangle you'll have to calculate a larger elliptic path with a larger rectangle.

Comment: This is some cool stuff, thanks! That last paragraph is especially useful.

Comment: Some useful hacks: 1. Instead of making the ellipse larger then the rectangle, keep the ellipse the same size and draw a rectangle of the outer color of the ellipse behind it. 2. Instead of white, the inner color often looks better when it is a washed out shade of the outer color.