# CSS Header Color graduatly change from top left to bottom right

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I was wondering if it is possible, with CSS and ASP.NET, to have a div fill itself from the top left corner to the bottom right corner like http://ictlyceum.deltion.nl/moodle/theme/deltion2/logo_small.jpg

I have not yet tried anything to attempt to do this since I'm not sure if it actually is possible.

Comment: Maybe useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392956/how-do-i-draw-a-circular-gradient

Comment: Might be usefull, but I wish to have it as a background-image. If this is not possible I guess I could try create a elipse and show it in the header part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@levisaxos; may be you want a gradient so you can use `css3 gradient property` http://css-tricks.com/examples/CSS3Gradient/

you can generate the gradient http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

check this article for more http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-css-gradient

Comment: I've used your 2nd link to create a gradient, which works for all browsers. However when I open it in IE9 it shows in very different colors then I wanted. It seems it only takes 2 colors instead of 3...  how to fix?

Comment: may be because you can use only two color in IE filter check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847.aspx

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
body{
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left top,
    right bottom,
    color-stop(0%,#f00),
    color-stop(50%,#F6FF00),
    color-stop(100%,#fff));
}
```

See it run here: http://jsfiddle.net/t5W2z/

Comment: This works except  for that it only shows from left till right. I wish for it to gradient from top to bottom also. I might be able to get this done myself however. Thank you !

Comment: Nope, this should also be from top to bottom.

Comment: I see the example yet in my own project it only goes from left to right. Could this be due to some old version of something?