# Is it possible to create a PathGradientBrush with radial gradient and outside fill

Tags: gdi+

I want to create a brush that would be repeated a ID2D1RadialGradientBrush and fill outside boundary of the path.

Example of ID2D1RadialGradientBrush:
[image]

In this example ID2D1RadialGradientBrush for all primitives have same width and height. Left rectangle and ellipse have same bounds as brush. Right rectangle and ellipse have increased length.

After some research i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5393056/3907965.)

I tried both methods and that's what I got:

**Method with points:**

[image]

**Method with path**

[image]

Method with points bad because them don't fill radial.

Method with path bad because rectangle and ellipse is not painted over completely.

MSDN [say](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/7fswd1t7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> By default, a path gradient brush does not extend outside the boundary of the path

I tried to find "non default" method to setup a brush, but I could not find a method.

How do setup the PathGradientBrush so that it looked like a ID2D1RadialGradientBrush

**PS:** Of course, i can increase the size of the brush to make it look like, but for me it is not very suitable solution.

Comment: I have the exactly same issue